# load data local infile - command not found

Tags: mysql, linux, mariadb

As part of a Linux-script, i tried to insert data from a file into a table.

If I try to use the following SQL statement I get this answer from the Server:

```
./load_test.sh: line 28: -h$SERVER: command not found.
```

What does it mean?

```
$MYSQL -h$SERVER -P3306 -uroot -p $DB -e "load data local infile '/var/lib/mysql/scripts/load_test/test.del' INTO TABLE TAB_SNAP_GET_DB_V97 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'"
```

Comment: Variable `MYSQL` seems to be undefined or empty.

Comment: MYSQL is defined as MYSQL=/usr/local/bin/mysql

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the code of your script that sets `MYSQL`. The error message means that the shell sees `-h$SERVER` as the first word in a line 28 of your script which means that `$MYSQL` is empty. `$SERVER` in the error message is also suspicious. Maybe you should show your complete script. Add `echo "MYSQL=${MYSQL}#"` or similar to your script before the line 28 to see the value, or add `set -x` at the beginning of your script.

Comment: BTW: What you show in the question is not a response from the MySQL server but an error message from the shell.

Comment: Got it. I definded MYSQL but in line 28 i used $mysql.

Comment: That means you did not copy your code to the question but somehow modified it. Since your question did not contain a [mcve] we could not find the problem.

Comment: It may be defined, but did you "export" it?  (See the 'shell' documentation)